# Storybook dont work with absolute path in gatsby

Tags: typescript, gatsby, storybook

i installed a plugin recently to handle absolute paths in gatsby called gatsby-plugin-root-import, and until i set it up the storybook was working fine, however when i run an absolute path it throws an error.

here does not throw error

```
import { URL_DEFAULT } from '../../utils/globalVars'
```

but here an error is thrown

```
import { URL_DEFAULT } from 'utils/globalVars'
```

error:

```
resolve 'utils/globalVars' in '/home/arthur/Área de Trabalho/mirror/src/components/Button'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /home/arthur/Área de Trabalho/mirror/package.json (relative path: ./src/components/Button)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      /home/arthur/Área de Trabalho/mirror/src/components/Button/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/arthur/Área de Trabalho/mirror/src/components/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
```

config plugin gatsby:

```
const path = require('path')
    {
          resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-root-import',
          options: {
            resolveModules: [path.join(__dirname, 'libs')],
            utils: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'components', 'utilities')
          }
        },
```

config preview Storybook:

```
global.___loader = {
  enqueue: () => {},
  hovering: () => {},
}
// This global variable prevents the "__BASE_PATH__ is not defined" error inside Storybook.
global.__BASE_PATH__ = "/"
// Navigating through a gatsby app using gatsby-link or any other gatsby component will use the `___navigate` method.
// In Storybook, it makes more sense to log an action than doing an actual navigate. Check out the actions addon docs for more info: https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/essentials/actions
window.___navigate = pathname => {
  action("NavigateTo:")(pathname)
}
```

tsConfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // "baseUrl": "src",
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["dom", "es2017"],
    // "allowJs": true,
    // "checkJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"]
}
```

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@styled-icons/boxicons-regular": "^10.37.0",
    "@styled-icons/boxicons-solid": "^10.34.0",
    "@styled-icons/fa-brands": "^10.34.0",
    "@styled-icons/material": "^10.28.0",
    "@styled-icons/material-outlined": "^10.28.0",
    "@styled-icons/remix-fill": "^10.18.0",
    "next": "10.1.3",
    "next-pwa": "^5.2.21",
    "polished": "^4.1.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-slick": "^0.28.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0",
    "styled-media-query": "^2.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.16",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.13.0",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.2.9",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.2.9",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.12.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.6",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.1.9",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.14",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.5",
    "@types/react-slick": "^0.23.4",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.9",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.22.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.22.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.12.0",
    "eslint": "^7.25.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.0.4",
    "husky": "^6.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-styled-components": "^7.0.4",
    "lint-staged": "^11.0.0",
    "plop": "^2.7.4",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4"
  }
```

webpack Storybook in main.js:

```
webpackFinal: async config => {
    // Transpile Gatsby module because Gatsby includes un-transpiled ES6 code.
    config.module.rules[0].exclude = [/node_modules\/(?!(gatsby)\/)/]
    // Use babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries to remove static queries from components when rendering in storybook
    config.module.rules[0].use[0].options.plugins.push(
      require.resolve("babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries")
    )
    return config
  },
```